# Parallel.For is slower?

Tags: c#, .net

Having a strange issue with Parallel.For in .NET 6 where the Parallel.For runs slower and is not using more than a single CPU core?

20,000 records

Parallel for finishes in 1 min 46 sec

```
            var options = new ParallelOptions()
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8
            };

            Parallel.For(0, vehicles.Count(), options, i =>
            {
                vehicles[i].VehVIN = aesGcm.Encrypt(vehicles[i].VehVIN?.Trim());
                _myRepository.UpdateVehicleAsync(vehicles[i]);
            });
```

Standard loop finishes in 1 min 43 sec:

```
            // Cycle the Vehicle entities
            for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.Count(); i++)
            {

                vehicles[i].VehVIN = aesGcm.Encrypt(vehicles[i].VehVIN?.Trim());
                _myRepository.UpdateVehicleAsync(vehicles[i]);

            }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I assume that the db update is the expensive thing here, doing more of them at once will slow things down

Comment: Agree with @pm100, and also, I find many people use `Parallel.For` as some sort of cudgel thinking it will simply magically improve performance.  It's great if your bottleneck is CPU bound (and you have spare cores), but virtually useless if it's IO bound.

Comment: @KirkWoll raises a good point, you're using SSD right?

Comment: I suspect the best perf will be to encrypt in parallel and update in one big batch (assuming your db supports it)

Comment: First, have you profiled the code so you know what the bottleneck is? Don't optimize without profiling.

Comment: It's updating a database so yes there is IO, but the amount actual data being processed is less than 1024 bytes per update so IO command que should have NO problem at all with this process.  I've profiled the code, the issue seems to be that multiple cores are NOT being used, the MaxDegreeOfParallelism is being ignored ... monitoring CPU cores shows single core usage only.